# Rstudio debugger exits debugging mode as soon as a value is checked

Tags: debugging, rstudio

I am trying to debug a simple program with the help of the Rstudio debugger. I first ran the program without the debugger. I then set a breakpoint as I have shown below, and checked "Source on Save". Then I saved the file, and the control came and halted at the breakpoint. I hit F10, typed b in the console, and got the value of b. I hit F10 again, and typed c in the console expecting to see the value of c. But, instead, Rstudio exited the debugger mode. Can someone explain what is happening?

[image]

Comment: View(c) works. Only c does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `c` command while using interactive debugging has a special meaning. It is used to `c`ontinue the normal execution of the function.

Similarly `n` is to execute the next line in the function, `s` is used to step into the function etc. So even these variables would behave differently if you use them as variables.

To get the contents of `"c"` variable you can use `print(c)` instead in the console.